# authorization is failed in instagram api?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

when i sent the request for authorizing i get like
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Insufficient developer role"}

Answer (score 0):

Go to Roles > Instagram Users and add your Instagram account. Then go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/ to accept the Tester Invite from your app.

Comment: In Tester Invite the account is already added. still got the same exception.